# Lift Shtml.link

Tags: scala, lift

why Lift's `SHtml.link` method accepts just `NodeSeq` as one of the params? What should I do when I want to create link just at`<a>Something</a>` instead of nested one? How can I turn a `String` into `NodeSeq`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `xml.Text(someString)`. It’s a plain scala class.

Answer (score 2):

Use scala.xml.Unparsed
eg - `return Unparsed("String")` where string is some html string.